# How to debug core library of node in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm, node-debugger

In WebStorm I could go into `_stream_readable.js` belonging to Node core library by using Force Step Into button. But I couldn't add any breakpoints there.

Meanwhile I can do this in Chrome Devtools where there is a limitation you need http server to connect Chrome Dev with Node Application. It is not convenient sometimes.

Is there any way to debug core code in WebStorm?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Dev Tools deal with runtime code loaded in VM, WebStorm - with source files available on your disk. You can't create breakpoints in files that don't exist in your project/libraries. But you can step into runtime code while debugging.

**Node.js Core** library created by Webstorm for Node.js code completion (**Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM**, **Node.js Core**) includes `fs.js`, `stream.js`, etc. - all core modules provided by `builtin-modules` module, so some of the core files are available locally and included in project and thus accessible to the IDE. But undocumented and similar modules, like `_stream_readable` are not included.